# echo product description in magento if the products belongs to specific category

Tags: php, magento

I want to show a detailed product description after a short description on the product listing page.

I'm doing this:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); ?>
                <?php if(in_array(428, $_product->getCategoryIds())): ?>
                    <span><?php echo $_product->getDescription(); ?></span>

                <?php endif ?>
```

It doesn't echo the product description though, any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump` the return value of `$_product->getcategoryIds()`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `$_product->getCategoryIds()` contains 428?
If yes I just can recomend to check you to try replace 428 with '428'. I'm not sure it will help, but...

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this in the end, in case it helps anybody else:

```
  <?php if (Mage::registry('current_category') && Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() == 428) { ?>
   <?php
     $my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

    echo $my_product->getDescription();

     ?>

  <?php } ?>
```